# What cannot be done in web assembly with .Net?

Tags: c#, webassembly

I'm considering porting some c# code into a web-app with web assembly. I find plenty of warnings online that not everything can be done in WASM. For example, an [article in code mag](https://www.codemag.com/article/1809061/Re-Assembling-the-Web-with-Web-Assembly-and-Blazor) states:

> .NET Standard but not all of it. The WASM Mono implementation supports
> .NET Standard 2.0 and loads and can execute any assembly built to that
> target. However, there are things that .NET Standard 2.0 supports that
> simply don't work in the WASM implementation and so there are quite a
> few things that might throw NotSupported exceptions.

I'm aware you can't touch the DOM, and the sandbox will not allow you to make system calls, but I'm struggling to find an actual list of disallowed functions/.NET libraries. I'm not keen to spend months porting code only to find what I desired was technically impossible [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326089/blazor-wasm-sending-mail-throw-exception-system-platformnotsupportedexception-s?rq=1) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679594/blazor-captcha-issue-system-drawing-common-is-not-supported?rq=1) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911081/xml-in-blazor-wasm-system-platformnotsupportedexception-operation-is-not-s?rq=1).

Concretely, what is impossible to do, either technically or in practical terms?

Thanks